# Handling connection reset errors in Go

Tags: error-handling, go, runtime-error

On a plain Go HTTP handler, if I disconnect a client while still writting to the response, `http.ResponseWritter.Write` will return an error with a message like `write tcp 127.0.0.1:60702: connection reset by peer`.

Now from the `syscall` package, I have `sysca.ECONNRESET`, which has the message `connection reset by peer`, so they're not exactly the same.

How can I match them, so I know not to panic if it occurs ? On other ocasions I have been doing

```
if err == syscall.EAGAIN {
  /* handle error differently */
}
```

for instance, and that worked fine, but I can't do it with `syscall.ECONNRESET`.

**Update:**

Because I'm desperate for a solution, for the time being I'll be doing this very dirty hack:

```
if strings.Contains(err.Error(), syscall.ECONNRESET.Error()) {
    println("it's a connection reset by peer!")
    return
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The error you get has the underlying type `*net.OpError`, built [here](http://golang.org/src/pkg/net/fd_unix.go#L281), for example.

You should be able to type-assert the error to its concrete type like this:

```
operr, ok := err.(*net.OpError)
```

And then access its `Err` field, which should correspond to the syscall error you need:

```
operr.Err.Error() == syscall.ECONNRESET.Error()
```

Answer (score 14):

The answer by @zian is more useful than the accepted answer, but now on Go 1.13+ it is preferable to avoid manually unwrapping the errors:

```
if errors.Is(opErr,syscall.ECONNRESET) {
    fmt.Println("Found a ECONNRESET")
}
```

This has the benefit that you can also use it more generally, such as after:

```
resp, err := http.Get("http://127.0.0.1:4444")
```

Here this err would otherwise have an extra layer of wrapping (`*url.Error`) and would be missed by the condition @zian used without explicitly unwrapping it a third time.

Comment: Just a small note: `&syscallErr` (passed as an argument to `errors.As`) can be initialized  like this: `syscallErr := os.SyscallError{}`

Answer (score 12):

I came across this issue and the accepted answer was sufficient to point me in the right direction. However, the code it provides to check if the Error embedded inside `*net.OpError` is `ECONNRESET` is not complete, at least not for Golang 1.9.

The error embedded at `OpError.Err` is actually of type `*os.SyscallError` (https://golang.org/pkg/os/#SyscallError). The `Write()` function implemented by struct `*net.netFD` (which is what's being written to when sending a response over the network) looks like this:

```
func (fd *netFD) Write(p []byte) (nn int, err error) {
    nn, err = fd.pfd.Write(p)
    runtime.KeepAlive(fd)
    return nn, wrapSyscallError("write", err)
}
```

And wrapSyscallError:

```
func wrapSyscallError(name string, err error) error {
    if _, ok := err.(syscall.Errno); ok {
        err = os.NewSyscallError(name, err)
    }
    return err
}
```

The error inside the `*os.SyscallError` struct can be directly compared against syscall.ECONNRESET.

So, given an error returned from a network write (e.g. a call to `http.ResponseWritter.Write`), the full code block to determine if that error is ECONNRESET is:

```
if opErr, ok := err.(*net.OpError); ok {
    if syscallErr, ok := opErr.Err.(*os.SyscallError); ok {
        if syscallErr.Err == syscall.ECONNRESET {
            fmt.Println("Found a ECONNRESET")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@zian - thanks for your good solution to João Pinto's (and my) question : How can I match them, so I know not to panic if it occurs ?
As at go version 1.13, an improvement is to use the errors.Is function which does error unwrapping and testing sequentially 'under the hood'. For example :

```
if errors.Is(opErr,syscall.ECONNRESET) {
  fmt.Println("Found a ECONNRESET")
}
```

@SteveCoffman - adding to your good answer, cheers!

[Working with Errors in Go 1.13 - The Go Blog - Golang](https://blog.golang.org/go1.13-errors)

Comment: Oh, good point. I incorporated that in my answer now.